# jquery get img src and add as background in another div

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the image src of the first img in a div and add it as a background into another div.

```
<ul class="list-parent">  
<li>
  <!-- add div with background img here -->
  <div class="img-parent">  
    <img src="image src origin">
    <img src="ignore this image">
    <img src="ignore this image">
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <!-- add div with background img here -->
  <div class="image-parent">  
    <img src="image src origin">
    <img src="ignore this image">
    <img src="ignore this image">
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I did something like:

```
var rssimg = $('.image-parent img:first-child').attr('src');
$('.img-target li').prepend('<div class="img-target" style="background-image:url(' + rssimg + ')"></div>');
```

But I'm only getting the source of the first image of the first .image-parent rather than the first src of each first image within their immediate parent.

I have already search for hours and tried different ways, but nothing has worked so far.  I'm practically new to JQuery, but I'm pretty sure there's got a be a solution to this.

Your expertise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something with `$.map` and `$.get`

```
var rssimg = $('div[class$=parent] img:first-child').map(function(){
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Now `rssimg` is an `Array` whose elements are urls of the images which are descendents of `<div>`s which have `class` which ends with parent, and they can be accessed by the index.

Comment: Do you think you can give an example on how to access by the index? What would be the syntax? Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think I was able to figure it out.  This is what I did:
'$.each (rssimg, function(i, val) {
    $('.list-parent li').eq(i).prepend('<div class="img-target" style="background-image:url(' + rssimg[i] + ')"></div>');
});
    '